# Unable to understand selenium code written in Java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

i'm using selenium1.0 from 3 months. i'm new to webdriver. any 1 please tel me what this code wil do

```
(new WebDriverWait(driver, 30)).until(new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
                public Boolean apply(WebDriver d) {
                    return d.getTitle().toLowerCase().startsWith("Java Developer");
                }
```

Answer (score 3):

It makes the web driver wait for 30 seconds maximum, until the title in lowercase starts with "Java Developer". Which of course is impossible, since `J` and `D` are uppercase chars. So it will always wait for 30 seconds.